# Why there is no DTD in strings.xml and styles.xml?

Tags: android

I created a new android studio project and found that there is no

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

tag at the beginning of `strings.xml` and `styles.xml` but it is present in `colors.xml`.

Why it is not present in the `strings.xml` and `styles.xml`?

Is the absence of this tag in `strings.xml` and `styles.xml` is fine?

Is that fine to add manually into `strings.xml` and `styles.xml` files?

Thanks!!!

Comment: "Why it is not present...?" -- a Google engineer forgot, I guess. "Is the absence of this tag... is fine?" -- yes. "Is that fine to add manually...?" -- yes.

Comment: it's a pretty interesting question though, I've honestly never noticed it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is called the "XML declaration" line and it is technically optional.

> Why is it not present in the strings.xml and styles.xml?

That maybe due to a technical difficulty on your android studio which can be fixed with a restart.

> Is the absence of this tag in strings.xml and styles.xml fine?

The presence of it is not compulsory but the absence of it may lead to compile time error when you insert non ASCII characters to the file, like `Norwegian æ ø å , or French ê è é.`

> Is it fine to manually add it into strings.xml and styles.xml files?

Totally yes! And you even have extra options at your disposal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Comment: `That maybe due to a technical difficulty on your android studio which can be fixed with a restart.`  definitely disagree with this, it's not due to an android studio problem at all

Comment: Excellent for extra tags encodings, great. Thank you so much sir.